# Verifying a Gaussian Process

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose I have two independent standard normally distributed random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ and form the linear combination of these to define a random process {$Y_t$} by; $$Y_t=X_1\,\text{cos}(t)+X_2\,\text{sin}(t).$$

Then $Y_t$ is also standard normally distributed.

However, I would like to know how the joint distribution $Y_{t_1,t_2}$ would be distributed. My intuition is that $Y_{t_1}$ and $Y_{t_2}$ are both dependent random variables and so their joint distribution may not be normal. How would I go about forming this joint distribution?

The reason I am asking this is because I want to verify that $Y_t$ is a Gaussian process, and hence want to show that the finite-dimensional distributions are all Gaussian.

Comment: Having thought about this a little more, I believe that I could write create the joint distribution of $Y_{t_1,t_2}$ by applying a deterministic matrix to $X=\begin{pmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{pmatrix}$, which would easily give that the distribution is bivariate normal and hence that the process is Gaussian (by generalising the above for a finite number of dimensions).